# How to define my AppDelegate as instance variable of a class it instantiates?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am starting a C++ project (using Cocos2d-x, but doesn't really matter) where my AppDelegate creates a IntroMenu object. I want to define the AppDelegate as instance variable of my IntroMenu class but I don't manage to do it...

Here is how my IntroMenu is defined:

**IntroMenu.h**

```
class  IntroMenu : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor
{
public:
    AppDelegate* _app;
    //etc...
}
```

**IntroMenu.m**

```
CCScene* IntroMenu::scene()
{
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::node();
    IntroMenu *layer = IntroMenu::node();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}
```

When I instanciate IntroMenu from my AppDelegate, I proceed like this in AppDelegate:

```
introScene = IntroMenu::scene();
((IntroMenu*)introScene)->_app = this;
```

`_app` is a public variable (of type AppDelegate) of IntroMenu.

The problem is that `_app` is a null pointer when I want to use it later in other methods of AppDelegate.

How to instantiate properly IntroMenu and its variable `_app`?

Thanks !!

Comment: How can you get a pointer to `IntroMenu` from a pointer to `CCScene`? Is `IntroMenu` inheriting from `CCScene`? While I have no experience of Cocos2d, it seems to me that you need to get the _child_ of `introScene` that points to the `IntroMenu` class as `CCScene` has no `_app` member.

Comment: There should be a functionality similar to the one in UIKit, as in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]. As a former C++ programmer your public member variable approach makes me feel violated.

Answer (score 2):

I think right answer is:

```
AppDelegate *aD = ((AppDelegate*)CCApplication::sharedApplication());
aD->myAppDelegateMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

This way you can access your app delegate class :)